# Instagram API receiving unrelated media for specified hashtag

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm currently making requests to the Instagram API. Specifically, the endpoint `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` (specified [here](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/#get_tags_media_recent)).

Using the example tag `doggo`, I'm receiving mostly responses whose JSON `tags` contain `doggo`; however, I also receive media with empty `tags` entries:

[image: AAAAAAAAAAA]

Would anybody happen to know why this sort of situation might occur? The range of untagged media that appears to slip in varies wildly in relevance to the specified tag, so I'm curious if this is a bug or some sort of Instagram algorithm to infer a media item's relevance to the specified tag.

Thanks!

Comment: could be a bug, the username has `doggo` in it ?

Comment: @krisrak that's the user below the one I have selected in the screenshot. I've scanned the media posts and cannot find anything on the media object itself or the user who posted the media that has any trace of the specified tag.

Comment: check the 12 comments in that media

Comment: @krisrak my colleague had suggested that that was the reason they were showing up (since sometimes users tend to post media with no caption first, and then follow up with a comment containing a bunch of hashtags). I was hoping for a conclusive answer, as this is currently just the theory. I don't want to expend API calls checking comments on every post but so far this is the most likely answer.

Comment: yes, that the reason, I post all of my posts with no hashtag in caption and then a comment with all hashtags, Instagram API sometimes has all those hashtags in the tags:[ ], but sometimes it is empty for some posts. check my posts: @krisrak, the first 2 has no tags, others have, so its an instagram bug

Comment: @krisrak would be really nice if the tags array consistently contained the tags that the image was truly tagged with. It'll suck to make additional API calls to scan the comments. Thanks for all your help!